# Permission denied (publickey)（I can log in Tiger but can not upload the file）

Tags: macos, ssh, scp

I want to transfer a file to a server, but when I use the command 
`scp -r /home/localName/course-account.log name@ip:/Users/name/java/`
then I get the error

> name@ip: Permission denied (publickey) lost connection

Do I need to edit the `id_rsa` or `id_rsa.pub`?

I can log in at the server, but I cannot upload a file!
I have saved the remote Public Key to the local name "key" and I set iTerm2 to log in automatically, using the config to find the "key".
I have already added the remote key to the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, but it does not work.

`scp -r /home/localName/course-account.log name@ip:/Users/name/java/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to login via ssh and your key, your public key must be present on the server in a specific file.

- Open your public key file (`id_rsa.pub`)
- Login to the server
- Paste the content of the public key file to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

Comment: Thank you for it, but id_rsa.pub is using for git.  I have already created the public key, and paste on **GitHub**, doesn't it works if I paste on the ssh server authorized_keys?

Comment: You can use the same key. That should not pose any problem.